# Escalar app en Heroku para multiples usuarios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Soy nuevo en Heroku . Tengo una aplicación de un sistema de reservas en Ruby on Rails, que ya la subí Heroku y esta en pleno funcionamiento para un usuario. Quiero escalar esa aplicación para que múltiples usuarios puedan utilizarla, la cual requiere que cada usuario acceda a su propia base de datos. Cada usuario tiene una aplicación cliente en ambiente Windows, que dialoga con la aplicación  web en el servidor estableciendo un contacto cada 1/2 hora para consultar cambios en una base de datos (en el servidor, perfectamente  esa aplicación podría estar "durmiendo" en el periodo que no se la consulta).. Por favor si alguien puede ayudarme, le agradezco muchísimo

Comment: Googlea `rails multi tenancy` y encontrarás varios artículos que te podrán ayudar en esa tarea. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Alter Lagos, me diste una linea de análisis que no había visto hasta ahora. Saludos